# Database modeling Idea

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema, data-modeling, entity-attribute-value

is it a good idea to model my database like this?

A table for tables,
A table for columns,
A table for data.

```
create table "Tables"
{
tbl_ID,
tbl_name,
}

create table "columns"
{
col_ID
col_Name
tbl_ID (Foreign key to tables)
}

create table "Datas"
{
data_ID
data_Name
col_ID(foreign key to columns) 
}
```

thats just the main Idea thou.

if so is their anything you could suggest I could do to make a dynamic model.

Comment: Looks pretty standard

Comment: [OTLT and EAV: the two big design mistakes all beginners make](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html)

Comment: If you can't tell what the purpose of these tables is at a glance, maybe you're on the wrong track. These are way too generic. If you want a schemaless database, look at using JSON columns or something more free-form like MongoDB.

Comment: what is a good working alternatives to this kind of design?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Terrible idea, with respect.

Design entities - tables - that reflect the stuff in your application.

There's nothing to be gained from using a dbms to build a dbms. Use the dbms to model your real-world problem space.

But don't worry, many of us have been tempted by this kind of design.